# opencart resize images in a string containing html

Tags: php, html, opencart

I have a string from a customers signature in the variable $signature .
The string is html and will probably contain  tags.
How can i resize all the images within that string to a maxmimum set size to stop people including massive pictures but still have all the html with resized  tags in the variable $signature.
I would need to set either a maximum size or some sort of ratio to reduce the image displayed.

example string :

```
$signature = '<b>test text</b><img src="http://kushsrivastava.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/test.gif">'
```

Any help would be brilliant thanx..

Comment: Did you mean size as in visual size or file size?

Comment: Visual size , i some how need to parse the html $variable and add height / width to all <img> tags set to a maximum value and keep the aspect ration of the original images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could wrap it all in a style and add a fix to the stylesheet.

so when you output the sig on the page, you wrap it...

```
<div class="sigstyle">
<?php echo $signature; ?>
</div>
```

Then, in your stylesheet, add a class...

```
.sigstyle img { 
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `CSS` property to re-size your image

```
$signature = '<b>test text</b><img src="http://kushsrivastava.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/test.gif" width="100px" height="100px">';
```

Comment: No use as the user can enter any img url themselves in their signature textarea box so the image could be 1000px x 1000px and when i come to display the users signature i want to make sure that any image tags are resized to a max set value.

Comment: @JustineSmithies : means you want make it dynamic `width and height` in the `$signature` variable